# Variable is returning null in console

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on an anchor I pass the attribute ' data-target ' to my **target** var. In the scroll function I pass the target in the parameters and everything works well. My problem is that the console logs an error showing the target returning a null in this line:

```
var targetPosition = target.offsetTop;
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
var headerHeight = document.querySelector('header').offsetHeight;

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var anchor_location = this.getAttribute('data-target');
        // Find the element with ID that matches data-target value.
        var target = document.querySelector(anchor_location);
        scroll(target, headerHeight);
    })
}

function scroll(target, headerHeight) {
    var start = null;
    var duration = 1100; //d
    var targetPosition = target.offsetTop;
    var startPosition = window.pageYOffset; //b
    var distance = targetPosition - startPosition - headerHeight; //c
    console.log(distance);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);


    function step(timestamp) {
        if (!start) start = timestamp;
        var progress = timestamp - start; //t
        // window.scrollTo(0, distance*(progress/duration) + startPosition);
        window.scrollTo(0, quintic(progress, startPosition, distance, duration));
        if (progress < duration) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
    }
}

// http://www.gizma.com/easing/ [easing equations]
function quintic (t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d/2;
    if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
    t -= 2;
    return c/2*(t*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
};
```

Comment: We would need to see the HTML, as one explanation is that the click event is fired on an element that has no `data-target` attribute, or one with a wrong value.

Comment: You're right. Should have figured that out myself. During the testing of the script I only provided one anchor with a data-target attribute. So every other anchor clicked should return 'null'. My anchor_location passes a data-target attribute of any anchor, but if there's none; then the target is 'null'. I think that's it. Thanks!